# Need help fast -- CoreData error

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, exception, core-data

need help desperately ahead of a demo in a few hours...  App was working on my test device fine last night.  Added some data (as I always do) this morning and now I get this error during a save operation:

```
        Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing:
    *** -[NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value
(key: _ContentChange_OldIndexPathKey) with userInfo (null)

        *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
    reason: '*** -[NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value
(key: _ContentChange_OldIndexPathKey)'
```

The funny thing is that if I download my sqlite file to my Mac and feed it into the simulator, everything works just fine.  The crash only occurs on the test device.

Any ideas?

Comment: On the face of it, the error message looks fairly conclusive. You sure everything is the same between the 2 environments?

Comment: You're trying to insert a `nil` into a dictionary. Where does that value (`userInfo`) come from?

Comment: Update: I fixed it, though I don't know why.  This error was occurring in a UIViewController that contains a UITableView and an  NSFetchedResultsController.  It is normally the delegate for my NSFetchedResultsController and implements the appropriate methods for table updates.  I had a feeling it was one of those methods that was causing the problems.  So I commented out the line making the ViewController the delegate for the NSFetchedResultsController, and all worked fine.  This means some features won't work (table updates based on changes to the model) but I can live with that for my demo.

Comment: ed94133: Can you run your app on the device under the debugger? If so, see what you can find out about the attempted insertion.

Answer (score 4):

I too was encountering this error. Nullifying the NSFetchedResultsController delegate does stop it from crashing, but is not a fix. The problem seems to be specifying a sort key in the NSFetchRequest which is null for some objects. Some sort call made in NSFetchedResultsController expects none null values.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old post but I will give my comment anyway :)

I have experienced similar problem and deleting the cache for the NSFethedReultController solved the problem.

```
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:<cacheName>];
```