# Core data doesn't fetch objects

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Hello here is my NSFetchedResultsController implementation:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSLog(@"context - %@",self.context);
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Categories" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.context sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"root"];
    _fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
//    [[self context] fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"Categories" withPredicate:
//     nil] ;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects is always nil.
 Here is how I'm adding objects:

```
-(void)addCategoryWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    NSLog(@"context - %@",self.context);
    Categories *category = (Categories *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Categories" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    category.name = name;
    NSLog(@"category name - %@",category.name);
    category.displayOrder = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    //        site.displayOrder = displayOrder;

    NSError __block *error;
    if (![self.context save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Error saving - %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

There is no error, no nothing. If I see my .sqlite file in the Documents directory it's modified, but I can't get any objects fetched. Really weird, I'm using fundamentally the same codes for my other app and it works just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you call `performFetch` somewhere? - Also I would not specify a `cacheName` if `sectionNameKeyPath = nil`.

Comment: Completely forgot about performFetch. It seems not been programming for a while have it's effects. However a good experience learned here, thanks! Just one question - why not specify cache when sectionNameKeyPath is nil?

Comment: I will put that into my answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `performFetch` on the fetched results controller once. Otherwise it will not fetch anything and also not track changes. For example add

```
NSError *error;
if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    // error handling
}
```

at the end of the `fetchedResultsController` getter method.

<strike>*Remark:* It seems that specifying a `cacheName` without `sectionNameKeyPath` can cause problems, see [UITableView with NSFetchedResultsController Does Not Load the Second Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677076/uitableview-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-does-not-load-the-second-time). Since the cache is used to cache section information, it is not needed anyway if you don't have sections.</strike>

*Update:* The preceding remark is no longer valid, it turned out that the problems in the linked question had a different cause.