# NSFetchedResultsController and cacheName inconsistent

Tags: ios, objective-c

When using a `cacheName` on a `NSFetchedResultsController` the `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` sometimes (but consistently) returns an incorrect number of objects, which will result in a crash when looking up a managedObject at a certain indexPath that is out of bounds. This seems to only happen when using a `cacheName` and when the number of results in a section changed from > 0 to 0.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger numberOfRows = 0;
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    numberOfRows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    return numberOfRows;
}
```

Number of rows returns 2, but

```
[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]
```

returns 0

Does somebody know or workaround or should I just never use a `cacheName` when I know the result count can be 0?

Comment: That should not happen. Did you implement all FRC delegate methods, including `controller:didChangeSection:`? Is the first sort descriptor consistent with `sectionNameKeyPath`?

Comment: Yes and yes. When I set sectionNameKeyPath to nil, nothing is wrong.

Comment: A `sectionNameKeyPath` should be no problem. Can you show more code, e.g. the construction of the FRC and the delegate methods? Anything else that might be important, such as an additional (background) managed object context?

Comment: I meant to say 'cacheName', not 'sectionNameKeyPath'.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677076/uitableview-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-does-not-load-the-second-time for a perhaps similar strange problem with a FRC cache. I would just not use a cache unless you have a performance problem.